# Right-click the Persistence Unit and select Generate Faces Pages is missing in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2020.2.2

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jsf, persistence, java-ee-8

I try to generate JSF from entities.When I  Right-click the Persistence Unit and select Generate Faces Pages which is not found.
[Missing Generate Faces Pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwTEv.png)
I am working with JAVA EE 8 and I choose as libraries:
[Chosen frameworks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeMI8.png)
I look for many articles online but without any progress any help please:
https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2006/11/jsf-application-in-just-two-clicks/
I am deeply convinced that is an issue of configuration.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This action is not longer available in current IDE versions.

Comment: Thanks for your response.I have installed IntelliJ Idea 2020.1 and it works for me.